# Compositing Viewer Node No Background

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

No preview image showing up when I plug the Viewer node in. I read elsewhere that I needed to render the image first. That worked for a little while but now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Just toggle one of your nodes *off* and *on* again.
*Viewer/Composite* nodes refresh *only* when there's a change in the compositor.

You can use <kbd>M</kbd> on your keyboard to Mute/Unmute a node.
Or just disconnect and reconnect it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers (like myself), also make sure you have actually *rendered* your layer(s) first. The compositor does not render them for you.

You will know you have a rendered layer when you see the thumbnail of the “Render Layers” node, just as you see in [jachym michal’s answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164069/62918).